# .NET Date format in the database because of JSON conversion

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am trying get the same date format as it is the database like `12/2/2020` but the json is converting the date like `/Date(1606845600000)/`

I want to keep the date the same as it is the database. I just need the date portion not the time.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Here is the Model I am using

```
 public Item()
        {
            this.Inventories = new HashSet<Inventory>();
            this.PurchasesDetails = new HashSet<PurchasesDetail>();
            this.SalesDetails = new HashSet<SalesDetail>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int MeasurementID { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal BuyPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal SalePrice { get; set; }
        public decimal CommisionRate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> MftDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ExpDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> StockLimit { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }

        public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
       // [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Inventory> Inventories { get; set; }
        public virtual Measurement Measurement { get; set; }
       // [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<PurchasesDetail> PurchasesDetails { get; set; }
       // [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<SalesDetail> SalesDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the code I am using

```
var itemz = new
        {
            item.Id,
           item.Code,
            item.Name,
            item.Quantity,
            item.BuyPrice,
            item.SalePrice,
            item.CommisionRate,
            item.CategoryID,
            item.UserID,
            item.MeasurementID,
            item.MftDate,
            item.ExpDate,
            item.StockLimit,
            item.Description
        };
        return Json(new { data = itemz }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

here is the output

```
{
"data": {
"Id": 10,
"Code": "33",
"Name": "dd",
"Quantity": 44,
"BuyPrice": 45,
"SalePrice": 50,
"CommisionRate": 0,
"CategoryID": 6,
"UserID": "57e8c446-ccb7-4399-a7f3-898ccc8066fd",
"MeasurementID": 1,
"MftDate": "/Date(1606845600000)/",
"ExpDate": "/Date(1579543200000)/",
"StockLimit": 7,
"Description": null
}
}
```

Comment: How is the value to mftDate set? Can you provide the item class?

Comment: Are you storing the time as well as the date?

Comment: Sorry. I have edited and added the item class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `convert` your date to the correct format.

As a result, you should change your code like below

```
var itemz = new
{
    item.Id,
    item.Code,
    item.Name,
    item.Quantity,
    item.BuyPrice,
    item.SalePrice,
    item.CommisionRate,
    item.CategoryID,
    item.UserID,
    item.MeasurementID,
    MftDate = item.MftDate == DateTime.MinValue ? "" : item.MftDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),

    ExpDate = item.ExpDate == DateTime.MinValue ? "" : item.ExpDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
    item.StockLimit,
    item.Description
};
```

Comment: So it says invalid anyonmous type member declarator & No overload for method “ToString” takes 1 arguments error when adding ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),

I tried ``` DateTime? MftD = item.MftDate;
            MftD.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

            DateTime? ExpD = item.ExpDate;
            ExpD.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

            var itemz = new
            {
                
                item.MftD,
                item.ExpD,
               
            };```
         But no luck

Comment: Can you give me your type of  `item.MftDate, item.ExpDate,` class? Is it `DateTime` type?

Comment: How to add them in var itemz = new
    { }
Please

Comment: I am getting this error. Please take a look.
https://imgur.com/R4gB2iZ

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the anonymous type in itemz. So you are managing that. If you want to keep some part of the date time in the json result. You only need to specify as a string for example in the desired format.

```
var itemz = new
    {
        item.Id,
       item.Code,
        item.Name,
        item.Quantity,
        item.BuyPrice,
        item.SalePrice,
        item.CommisionRate,
        item.CategoryID,
        item.UserID,
        item.MeasurementID,
        item.MftDate.ToString("dd/MM HH:mm:ss"),
        item.ExpDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
        item.StockLimit,
        item.Description
    };
    return Json(new { data = itemz }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Here you have more information about [.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.8)  method.

Comment: Nice answer, Antonio :)

Comment: it's how there are in the model

``` public Nullable<System.DateTime> MftDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ExpDate { get; set; }```

So it says invalid anyonmous type member declarator & No overload for method “ToString” takes 1 arguments error when adding ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),

Comment: OK. so your types are Nullable<System.DateTime> for both properties. in this case you have to check if the date has value and define a Name for the property as Anonymous did.

e.g:
var itemz = new
{
 item.Id,
 item.Code,
 item.Name,
 MftDate = item.MftDate.HasValue ? item.MftDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM HH:mm:ss") : string.Empty
};
return Json(new { data = itemz }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);